# localStorage is not defined

Tags: local-storage, stenciljs, stencil-compiler

I'm using `localStorage` and sessionStorage on a StencilProject.
When I'm running `npm run dev --prod` it's ok.
When I'm running `npm run build` this is KO. 
Even with this error, my app works great on Chrome but not in Firefox. 
The error is:

> localStorage is not defined

So I changed my call from `localStorage.getItem` to `window.localStorage`, so now I have the following error:

> Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined

Any idea on how using `localStorage` in prod compatibility?

[Code is here](https://github.com/StephaneC/StencilDialogFlow)

Comment: Interesting, I see it too. Seems like a bug in Stencil?

Comment: That said, I just added `window.localStorage.getItem('test')` to my own Stencil app, and was able to `npm run build` fine.

Comment: @Matthewsteele : which Stencil version do you have?

Comment: I just tried with `@stencil/core` v 0.1.0, and it worked okay.